# QUICKSORT Algorithm - JavaScript. Im stuck :(

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, quicksort

can anybody tell me why this generate infinite loop? Im stuck.
Maby i miss something?

```
const quickSort = function (arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return arr;
  }
  const pivot = arr[0];
  const smallerThanPivot = [];
  const highterThanPivot = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivot) {
      smallerThanPivot.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      highterThanPivot.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return [
    ...quickSort(smallerThanPivot),
    pivot,
    ...quickSort(highterThanPivot),
  ];
};
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Look at your if statement. When do things get added to "smaller than pivot"? And when do things get added to "higher than pivot"? And then ask yourself whether the code does what the variable names suggest should be happening. But on a JS syntax note: why are you declaring a const and then assigning a function? Just declare the function as a normal named function, don't block-scope what doesn't need block-scoping =)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. That's so little code that even `console.log` could help to spot the bug

Comment: I got the bug. Quick sort doesn't work beacuse the ' i < arr.length'. It should be ' i < arr.length - 1'. But why? Can anybody explain?

Comment: when you divide the array into two parts, the pivot itself shouldn't belong to either part. So if your pivot is array[0], you should start division with array[1], not [0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a simple mistake.
One trick for me when I started learning Javascript, is to add some `console.log` to make sure what is happening.

You were starting on position 0. but since zero is already the pivot, you don't need it in the cycle.
This was adding one position to the array on every cycle, making it infinite.

This is the correct function

```
const quickSort = function (arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
return arr;
  }
  const pivot = arr[0];
  const smallerThanPivot = [];
  const highterThanPivot = [];

  /*  //debug prints 
  console.log("Pivot: " + pivot);
  console.log("Length: " + arr.length ); 
  */

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivot) {
      smallerThanPivot.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      highterThanPivot.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return [
    ...quickSort(smallerThanPivot),
 pivot,
    ...quickSort(highterThanPivot),
  ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't filter `pivot` out from array
which leads to `[1, 2, 3]` being split into `[], [1, 2, 3]` beacuse pivot in placed into a higher part
Thus the array length is not reducen and you gen infinite loop

Comment: This is partially correct, but not entirely.
The pivot was being added to the return array, without being removed just like you said.
So the original function was calling the same pivot constantly, and adding it to an array, creating an infinite stack, and never finishing the callback cycle..
The result array was not `[]+[1,2,3]` but `[] + pivot + [1,2,3]`